# WebBrowser Component for Mac

Tags: macos, webbrowser-control

I am looking for some web-browser control for Mac, which is the root of my project and any programming language which supports browser can be used for development,

I tried Mono but that does not support Browser control for Mac.

I am completely new to Mac-world, if there is anyone can show me a list of possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re developing for Mac OS X, you should use [Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html), the Objective-C framework developed, published, and supported by Apple.

For the Web browser component, you can use the [WebKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html).

Comment: Does Webkit supports DOM and Browser Events/Interfaces?

Comment: @regexhacks I’m sure it supports DOM (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/DOMObjCBindings.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001206-BCIGCAIE)). What do you mean by browser events/interfaces?

Comment: I have developed using IE WebBrowser Component in .Net, using it I can capture events on webpage like some ajaxed page can change loading new content, I need to trap such events

Comment: @regexhacks There’s a `WebResourceLoadDelegate` protocol for notifications on resource loading. See the reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebResourceLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001914).

Comment: I think your answer is very much complete in your perspective (or as much asked by me), rest is the part of implementation

Answer (score 0):

Qt includes WebKit component. Usually Qt apps are developed with C++ in "Qt Creator" IDE. But Qt's WebKit implementation has several ugly bugs. Other WebKit implementations are better, but I don't know if they are available on Mac.

It is also possible to use Gecko XUL. But it looks more complex to me than Qt.